# Shared storage for multiple GCE VMs

Tags: nginx, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-compute-engine

/* I'm new here and I've done days of research. */

What is the best practice to share files with multiple autoscaling Google Compute Engine VMs?

I'm planning to set up an Instance group of VMs with NGINX for serving static files for multiple domains. These VMs would autoscale to n (multiply itself) and the files would change a lot. I need a storage for the files these VMs will serve.

So far I've found these solutions:

**1) Persistent disk + rsync** -> This should have the smallest latency, but when I reach GBs of files, autoscaled VMs would be syncing for a long time after they spawn, thus throwing 404s.

**2) Master VM without web server + nfs/smb** -> Small latency, but no redundancy.

**3) Cloud Storage + FUSE** -> Big latency, great redundancy, no SLA.

**4) Shared Persistent disk** -> Small latency, but read-only.

**5) NGINX + Cloud SQL/Bigtable/Spanner/Datastore** -> Mehish latency and I don't feel well about connecting webserver to a DB.

Are there any other better solutions?

Thanks

**EDIT:** The static files are multiple index.html files -> homepages of multiple domains.

Answer (score 1):

There is also:

**6) Firebase Hosting** - https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting

or

**7) another way** - I would personally go with **Cloud Storage** but not FUSE. Or at least not for serving. You can still use FUSE for writing to Bucket(s). Of course the best way would be to just use **Cloud Storage API** from within the application.

**For serving files:**

I would create a **Load balancer** with a **Backend bucket** the same bucket where the application writes. Also be careful to enable **Cloud CDN** on that **Load balancer**.

**More details at:**

Load balancer - https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/

Cloud CDN - https://cloud.google.com/cdn/

or just be bold and create now a load balancer at https://console.cloud.google.com/networking/loadbalancing/loadBalancers/list?project=

Comment: Hi, thanks for quick reply. How would Load balancer + Backend bucket handle multiple domains? And for the NGINX + Cloud Storage without FUSE, is this something I could use? https://gist.github.com/touhonoob/5364f6c9099609c826a4

Comment: There is no need to do that `NGINX+Cloud Storage` thing... this is **Cloud CDN**'s job!

Comment: First I thought that would be a dealbreaker, but after playing with Cloud Storage + Cloud CDN, I've found out that you can't have multiple domains pointing to single bucket. There is 1 unique domain : 1 bucket policy, you have to manually verify ownership of the domain when creating the bucket via TXT record and the bucket has to hold the FQDN, otherwise it wouldn't serve index.html :(

Answer (score 1):

For serving static files the best is definitely to use a **load balancer** and **backend buckets** with **Cloud CDN enabled**.
The load balancer have rules to forward traffic. For example it can intercept all requests by hosts, subdomain, or path.

```
*.mysite1.com    => bucket1
demo.mysite2.net => bucket1
test.mysite3.com => bucket2
```

Because files are served with **Cloud CDN**, the latency becomes minimal.
In order to write your files to a bucket you could use **FUSE**, or create files locally and use `gsutil cp`.

Persistent disks can only be shared within several Compute Engines in read mode. If you need write mode it won't work.

The last option Cloud SQL + Nginx is actually pretty good. Cloud SQL is way more fast than Mysql servers. And connection between cloud sql and gce is easy and reliable.
But it is more a matter of preferences here... if you feel comfortable writing the scripts that will read and write to it.

Comment: Hi Vincent, after playing with that, I've found out that it is not possible to point multiple domains to a single bucket if you need to serve (one or multiple) index.html. Each domain needs its own bucket.

Comment: That's correct there can be only one index.html per bucket or per subfolder